# Combine two Knockout Examples

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to get two examples from knockout.com working and I have yet to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/2863/

When running this project and using a debugger I get an error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return linesa }"
Message: linesa is not defined

From the original example I changed lines to linesa to see if anything else was screwing it up. It still did not like linesa

My main goal is to get these two samples working together. The Add a contact button works but the Add product does not work.

Thank you!

```
    <div class='liveExample'> 

    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <div id='contactsList'>
        <table class='contactsEditor'>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Phone numbers</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: contactsa">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
                        <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeContact'>Delete</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input data-bind='value: type' /></td>
                                    <td><input data-bind='value: number' /></td>
                                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addPhone'>Add number</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p>
        <button data-bind='click: addContact'>Add a contact</button>
        <button data-bind='click: save, enable: contactsa().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
    </p>

    <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>

</div>

<div class='liveExample'> 

    <table width='100%'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width='25%'>Category</th>
                <th width='25%'>Product</th>
                <th class='price' width='15%'>Price</th>
                <th class='quantity' width='10%'>Quantity</th>
                <th class='price' width='15%'>Subtotal</th>
                <th width='10%'> </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind='foreach: linesa'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select data-bind='options: sampleProductCategories, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: category'> </select>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="with: category">
                    <select data-bind='options: products, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.product'> </select>
                </td>
                <td class='price' data-bind='with: product'>
                    <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(price)'> </span>
                </td>
                <td class='quantity'>
                    <input data-bind='visible: product, value: quantity, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
                </td>
                <td class='price'>
                    <span data-bind='visible: product, text: formatCurrency(subtotal())' > </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Remove</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class='grandTotal'>
        Total value: <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(grandTotal())'> </span>
    </p>
    <button data-bind='click: addLine'>Add product</button>
    <button data-bind='click: save'>Submit order</button>

</div>

    var initialData = [
    { firstName: "Danny", lastName: "LaRusso", phones: [
        { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 121-2121" },
        { type: "Home", number: "(555) 123-4567"}]
    },
    { firstName: "Sensei", lastName: "Miyagi", phones: [
        { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 444-2222" },
        { type: "Home", number: "(555) 999-1212"}]
    }
];

var ContactsModel = function(contactstest) {
    var self = this;
    self.contactsa = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contactstest, function(contact) {
        return { firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones) };
    }));

    self.addContact = function() {
        self.contactsa.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phones: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function(contact) {
        self.contactsa.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function(contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            type: "",
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function(phone) {
        $.each(self.contactsa(), function() { this.phones.remove(phone) })
    };

    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contactsa), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));

function formatCurrency(value) {
    return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
}

var CartLine = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.category = ko.observable();
    self.product = ko.observable();
    self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
    self.subtotal = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.product() ? self.product().price * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
    });

    // Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
    self.category.subscribe(function() {
        self.product(undefined);
    });
};

var Cart = function() {
    // Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
    var self = this;
    self.linesa = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default
    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $.each(self.linesa(), function() { total += this.subtotal() })
        return total;
    });

    // Operations
    self.addLine = function() { self.linesa.push(new CartLine()) };
    self.removeLine = function(line) { self.linesa.remove(line) };
    self.save = function() {
        var dataToSave = $.map(self.linesa(), function(line) {
            return line.product() ? {
                productName: line.product().name,
                quantity: line.quantity()
            } : undefined
        });
        alert("Could now send this to server: " + JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
```

Comment: If I split these two examples into different examples they both work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewModel is a ContactsModel, since ContactsModel does not have a linesa property, it cannot render the contents of the table.

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: linesa'>
```

this is the offending line.

You are working with 2 ViewModels actually, the Cart ViewModel and the Contacts ViewModel.

you need to make a new ViewModel that implements both ViewModels and you can bind the views using  `with` binding.

Code:

```
function CombinedViewModel(){
  this.cart=new Cart();
  this.contact=new Contact();
}

ko.appyBindings(new CombinedViewModel());
```

and for the bindings

```
<div data-bind="with:cart"><!-- cart html view goes here --></div>
<div data-bind="with:contact"><!-- contact html view goes here --></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes complete sense! Here is the completed solution in case anyone else finds it helpful.  http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/2881/

Comment: Here is an updated example with the numbers working. http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/2889/